# Why does my CUDA kernel seem to do nothing?

Tags: c, cuda

I'm working on a system with a GTX Titan X GPU, CUDA 8.0, and driver version 367.48. My GPU is properly listed when I use `nvidia-smi`.

I am using the code below to perform numerical approximation of Pi and measure the execution time of the code for 5000 times. However, the kernel returns 0.0 as the approximation result. Why is this happening?

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include <stdio.h>

#define ITERATIONS 96000000
const int threads = 256; 

// Synchronous error checking call. Enable with nvcc -DEBUG
inline void checkCUDAError(const char *fileName, const int line)
{ 
    #ifdef DEBUG 
        cudaThreadSynchronize();
        cudaError_t error = cudaGetLastError();
        if(error != cudaSuccess) 
        {
            printf("Error at %s: line %i: %s\n", fileName, line, cudaGetErrorString(error));
            exit(-1); 
        }
    #endif
}

__global__ void integrateSimple(float *sum)
{
    __shared__ float ssums[threads];

    // Each thread computes its own sum. 
    int global_idx = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    if(global_idx < ITERATIONS)
    {
        float step = 1.0f / ITERATIONS;
        float x = (global_idx + 0.5f) * step;
        ssums[threadIdx.x] = 4.0f / (1.0f + x * x);
    }
    else
    {
        ssums[threadIdx.x] = 0.0f;
    }
    
    // The 1st thread will gather all sums from all other threads of this block into one
    __syncthreads();
    if(threadIdx.x == 0)
    {
        float local_sum = 0.0f;
        for(int i = 0; i < threads; ++i)
        {
            local_sum += ssums[i];
        }
        sum[blockIdx.x] = local_sum;
    }
}
int main()
{
    const float PI = 3.14159265358979323846264;
    int deviceCount = 0;

    printf("Starting...");
    
    cudaError_t error = cudaGetDeviceCount(&deviceCount);

    if (error != cudaSuccess)
    {
        printf("cudaGetDeviceCount returned %d\n-> %s\n", (int)error, cudaGetErrorString(error));
        return 1;
    }

    deviceCount == 0 ? printf("There are no available CUDA device(s)\n") : printf("%d CUDA Capable device(s) detected\n", deviceCount);

    /*--------- Simple Kernel ---------*/
    int blocks = (ITERATIONS + threads - 1) / threads;
    float *sum_d;
    float step = 1.0f / ITERATIONS;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 5000; ++i)
    {
        // Allocate device memory
        cudaMallocManaged((void **)&sum_d, blocks * sizeof(float));

        // CUDA events needed to measure execution time
        cudaEvent_t start, stop;
        float gpuTime;

        // Start timer
        cudaEventCreate(&start);
        cudaEventCreate(&stop);
        cudaEventRecord(start, 0);

        /*printf("\nCalculating Pi using simple GPU kernel over %i intervals...\n", (int)ITERATIONS);*/

        integrateSimple<<<blocks, threads>>>(sum_d);
        cudaDeviceSynchronize(); // wait until the kernel execution is completed
        checkCUDAError(__FILE__, __LINE__);

        // Stop timer
        cudaEventRecord(stop, 0);
        cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
        cudaEventElapsedTime(&gpuTime, start, stop);
        
        // Sum result on host
        float piSimple = 0.0f;
        for (int i = 0; i < blocks; i++)
        {
            piSimple += sum_d[i];
        }
        
        piSimple *= step;

        cudaFree(sum_d);

        // Stop timer
        cudaEventRecord(stop, 0);
        cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
        cudaEventElapsedTime(&gpuTime, start, stop);
        // Print execution times
        /*printf("\n======================================\n\n");*/
        printf("%.23lf,%.23lf,%f", piSimple, fabs(piSimple - PI), gpuTime/1000);
        printf("\n");
    }
    // Reset Device
    cudaDeviceReset();
    return 0;
}
```

output of last lines

0.00000000000000000000000,3.14159274101257324218750,0.000009 0.00000000000000000000000,3.14159274101257324218750,0.000009 0.00000000000000000000000,3.14159274101257324218750,0.000009 0.00000000000000000000000,3.14159274101257324218750,0.000008 0.00000000000000000000000,3.14159274101257324218750,0.000008 0.00000000000000000000000,3.14159274101257324218750,0.000008

Also, when I compile getting this warning:

> nvcc warning : The 'compute_20', 'sm_20', and 'sm_21' architectures are > deprecated, and may be removed in a future release (Use -Wno-deprecated-  gpu-targets to suppress warning).

Comment: It works fine on my system. A typical output line; `3.14135432243347167968750,0.00023841857910156250000,0.009575`.

Comment: @einpoklum Yes, that is correct. 
I also tried on another machine with GTX 1060 (6GB) and works but can't understand why is not working on that machine.

Comment: Are you compiling to the correct GPU architecture on your machine?

Comment: @AnderBiguri 
I am quite new to CUDA to be honest. I used :

```nvcc pi_cuda.cu -o pi_cuda```

whre pi_cuda.cu is the file.

Answer (score 1):

### Your specific case

It might just be that you're not actually checking for errors at all: Your error-checking function has its code `#ifdef`'ed-away when you're not explicitly compiling with -DDEBUG.

Also, as @AnderBiguri  suggested, make sure you're compiling for the correct microarchitecture (the nvcc `--gpucode/--gencode/--gpu-architecture` switches).

### The general problem

When a kernel seems to produce 0-valued output, you should:

#### Make sure you're checking for errors

You should either use the [CUDA Modern-C++ API wrappers](https://github.com/eyalroz/cuda-api-wrappers/issues) (caveat: I'm the author, so I'm biased), where all API calls are followed by checks for success; or you should manually add error checks after your CUDA API calls. Note: If you've written your own error-handling code, make sure it can actually get triggered and print something (e.g. pass something other than cudaSuccess to it).

#### Distinguish between "outputs zero" and "does nothing"

Try filling your output buffers with an initial pattern to see if anything gets written to them (e.g. `cudaMemcpy()` from a buffer containing `0xDEADBEEF` of something like that). Then, by examining the output, you can determine whether the kernel actually writes 0 values or not. If it writes 0's - then you need to debug your kernel. Otherwise...

#### Make sure the kernel is actually launched

If your kernel writes nothing to the output, then:

- it isn't being launched, or
- there's some runtime error during execution, or
- there's a bug in the code which makes threads finish execution without getting to their instructions to write to shared memory:

the first option is most likely, and in fact it's about the same as the second option, except that the error occurs before the launch. Double-check and triple-check your error handling code.

Then, use either the NSight Compute or NSight Systems profiler to see if your kernel actually gets launched and executed. If it is, then it's back to debugging. Try using carefully-placed `printf()` instructions or an actual debugger tool.

If you're getting an error during the kernel's run, you might be able to make use of the [CUDA Compute Sanitizer](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/sanitizer-docs/ComputeSanitizer/index.html) ([cuda-memcheck](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-memcheck/index.html) in earlier CUDA versions) to catch and identify it.

Comment: `nvcc pi_cuda.cu -o pi_cuda --gpu-architecture=compute_35` did the trick.
Thank you for the detailed instructions, I will look at more detail at the CUDA Modern-C++ API wrappers.